# Understanding script to check if file exists or not

Tags: bash, file, unix

I have below command to check if file exists or not and create it if it not available:

```
if test "${LOG_FILE:=}x" != "x"; then
    touch $LOGAP
    exit_code=$?
fi
```

Please help me in understanding this script, how the test condition `"${LOG_FILE:=}x" != "x"` is used for checking if exixts or not. I am using bash shell.

Comment: What shell are you using?

Comment: @easterbunny, It is bash shell

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Basic idea**
The script checks if `$LOG_FILE` variable is set. If it is, it touches the file with name stored in `$LOGAP`.

**Explanation**
Let's split it:

```
test == if
```

So

```
if test "${LOG_FILE:=}x" != "x"; then
```

is the same as

```
if [ "${LOG_FILE:=}x" != "x" ]; then
```

Let's do one test:

```
LOG_FILE="FILE_TEST"
echo "${LOG_FILE:=}x"
```

will output

```
FILE_TESTx
```

So what it is done is a checking of variable `LOG_FILE` being set or not. If it is set,

```
[ "${LOG_FILE:=}x" != "x" ]
```

will be

```
[ "FILE_TESTx" != "x" ]
```

which is true.

If `LOG_FILE` is not set,

```
[ "${LOG_FILE:=}x" != "x" ]
```

will be

```
[ "x" != "x" ]
```

which is false.

That is to say `x` is something to start with. You could change it to

```
[ "${LOG_FILE:=}HELLO_MY_NAME_IS_BLABLA" != "HELLO_MY_NAME_IS_BLABLA" ]
```

Finally, you have a

```
touch $LOGAP
```

which will `touch` (create a file if not created, update modified date if already exists). It also requires the variable `$LOGAP` to be set.

---

Have to say that the fastest way to check if a file exists is this:

```
if [ ! -f /tmp/foo.txt ]; then
 ...
fi
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Is there any difference between the command I mentioned in question and the if command with -f option? Are they just alternate solutions. Can I use the if command with -f option every time for checking if file exists?

Comment: I strongly suggest you to use `if [ -f file ]`. The one you posted just checks if variables are defined or not, no matter the file they indicate.

Comment: Also, when you do need to test a variable to see if it is set and not empty, this is better `[ -n "$variable" ]` (or to make sure it is empty `[ -z "$variable" ]`). If you wanted to test if the variable was set even if it was set to nothing, this works: `[ -n "${variable+set}" ]` (`${variable+set}` expands to the word "set" if the variable is set even if it is empty, and nothing at all if the variable isn't set - the + does the magic, the string "set" is arbitrary and you can use anything. If you replace + with :+ then the variable must be set and not empty.)